# Combine two FART replace scripts together

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have two batch scripts:

```
@echo off
FART -i -r "12739*" "&"  " AND " 

@echo off
FART -i -r "12739*" "CM/< "  "CM"
```

I want to make them into one? Is that possible? I tried to add a comma, or semi-colon but nothing worked, any ideas?

Comment: `FART -i -r "12739*" "&"  " AND " & FART -i -r "12739*" "CM/< "  "CM"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `FART` is a .bat or .cmd script, then you must use `CALL`.

```
@echo off
CALL FART -i -r "12739*" "&"  " AND " 
CALL FART -i -r "12739*" "CM/< "  "CM"
```

Comment: In what way does it not work? Did the two separate commands work correctly?

Comment: Please copy and paste any error message into the question. What happens if you put the "CM" line first?

Comment: Then CM only works, there is no error message, it doesn't execute thats all, but Ill just put them separately its fine